# Exponential fitting using scipy.optimize.curve_fit without good guess

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I want to find a model describing the data below.

```
x = array([50000.,  100000.,  150000.,  200000.,  250000.,  300000.,
    350000.,  400000.,  450000.,  500000.,  550000.,  600000.,
    650000.,  700000.,  750000.,  800000.,  850000.,  900000.,
    950000., 1000000.])
y = array([1.87792730e-06, 3.81015841e-07, 1.89900422e-07, 1.21302069e-07,
   8.39703240e-08, 6.18937868e-08, 4.98975718e-08, 3.97720839e-08,
   3.23420144e-08, 2.79493666e-08, 2.35548293e-08, 2.01505953e-08,
   1.81079429e-08, 1.59391671e-08, 1.37227044e-08, 1.30031234e-08,
   1.19076952e-08, 1.10967303e-08, 9.43339053e-09, 8.98627485e-09])
```

Looking at the distribution of the data points, it is expected that the data follow an exponential function. Thus I tried using scipy.optimize.curve_fit in the follow way.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

def f(x, a, b, c): 
    return a*np.exp(b*x)+c

curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=[np.min(y), -1, np.min(y)])
```

This doesn't give me any reasonable values of a, b, and c. I tried using several p0 settings but always the pcov matrix consists of inf only.

If you have data but no good guess about the parameters like this case, how could you achieve a reasonable fitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a graphical Python fitter using a different equation from an equation search on your posted data, it appears to give an excellent fit using the scipy default initial parameter estimates of all 1.0.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = numpy.array([50000.0, 100000.0, 150000.0, 200000.0, 250000.0, 300000.0, 350000.0, 400000.0, 450000.0, 500000.0, 550000.0, 600000.0, 650000.0, 700000.0, 750000.0, 800000.0, 850000.0, 900000.0, 950000.0, 1000000.0])
yData = numpy.array([1.8779273e-06, 3.81015841e-07, 1.89900422e-07, 1.21302069e-07, 8.3970324e-08, 6.18937868e-08, 4.98975718e-08, 3.97720839e-08, 3.23420144e-08, 2.79493666e-08, 2.35548293e-08, 2.01505953e-08, 1.81079429e-08, 1.59391671e-08, 1.37227044e-08, 1.30031234e-08, 1.19076952e-08, 1.10967303e-08, 9.43339053e-09, 8.98627485e-09])


def func(x, a, b, c): # from zunzun.com equation search
    return a / (b+numpy.power(x, c))


# these are the same as the scipy defaults
initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy method (without initial guess, without iterative calculus) which principle is explain in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

The non-linear regression is transformed into a linear regression thanks to an integral equation. The application to your problem and the numerical calculus is shown below.

Note that the criteria of fitting (least mean square) is not exactly with respect to the given data but with respect to the transform data with numerical calculus of the integral (noted S below). So, if the accuracy of the result isn't sufficient, an non-linear regression is necessary. The initial values to start the iterative process can be the values already found which are not far from the goal.

So, I think this answers to your question about finding initial guess.

[image]

Numerical example with your data :

[image]

[image]

Note : The result is very good for the high values of Y. But it is no accurate for the smallest values of Y. A post-treatment with non-linear regression will be probably necessary, depending on the criteria of fitting.

Note: In case of your example of data the calculus involves very high and very low exponents. It is recommended to apply convenient factors to the original data in order to bing it in an usual order of magnitude. This was not done for the above example of calculus to make it simpler to follow.

For information :

The integral equation allowing a linear regression is :

[image]